# Как получить KeyHashes для работы с facebook login в firebase

Tags: android, facebooksdk, firebase

Здравствуйте , для регистрации приложения в facebook надо задать  `key hashes` 
чтобы получить `key hashes` как я понял надо установить `openssl` 
и написать в `cmd` строки которые даёт `facebook` я следовал следующему примеру по установки `openssl` [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrdUYk1wDlA)

при открытии `cmd openssl` написал строки которые даёт `facebook` и получил следующую ошибку `openssl error :'keytool is invalid command'`

как получить `key hashes` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В приложении запустите вот этот метод в активити, передав контекст - выведет в логи то, что нужно лицокниге

```
/**
 * prints keyHashes for app.
 * need it for social logins
 */
public static void printHashKey(Context ctx)
{
    try
    {
        PackageInfo info = ctx.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(ctx.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures)
        {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            String hashKey = new String(Base64.encode(md.digest(), 0));
            Log.i(TAG, "printHashKey() Hash Key: " + hashKey);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "printHashKey()", e);
    }
}
```